# Is there a way to encrypt the entire hard drive after you have already installed Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, security, encryption, system

How would you go about encrypting your entire system drive after you already have installed Ubuntu? I have Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS and I am using a laptop so I would like to have my data encrypted.

Comment: you have to do a fresh install, there is no way to convert as encryption writes random data to the hard drive

Answer (score 0):

If it is just "data" you would like protected, you can try using software such as [VeraCrypt](http://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) to create a separate encrypted partition where you can put all your data into.